# URL encoding ampersand in href attribute

Tags: javascript, html, uri, url-encoding

I'm having some difficulty narrowing down the problem, I am wondering if anyone can help.

We are storing a URI in a  element href attribute. This URI is dynamically created. One of the URI path variables maps to an id of an element in our database. Recently, we have started to use ampersands on special occasions in the id. The URI looks something like "/{entityType}/{entityId}/moderation".

When the URL is built, we use the encodeURIComponent javascript function, effectively turning the ampersand into '%26'. By examining the data stored in the href attribute via a web development tool, it looks like it is stored correctly. However, when I mouse hover it only displays the ampersand in the url.

Other ids work fine, including things like single apostrophes, but with an ampersand, it looks like it is getting a page redirection error (I'm guessing the ampersand is making the url invalid). I've tried escaping the percent sign, making the ampersand turn into '%2526', thinking that the %25 portion will be decoded to just the percent sign (making the final result %26).

So far none of my tinkering has worked. Anyone have a suggestion for next steps or what may be going on? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you are doing?  Maybe a fiddle with an example?

Comment: It's a little hard to replicate since we are using an internal URL builder, but this is essentially what we are doing (pretty basic): http://jsfiddle.net/ozpenstillson/B5z44/2/

Comment: Looking at the fiddle the link is correct and I can see it is making the request with the encoded '&'.  The issue is happening at the server.  It is decoding anything that is uri encoded.  Since the '&' is reserved it is evaluating it at the point and breaks the url.  If you can I would drop the '&' or any of the reserved characters.